# How to center text with PIL?

Tags: python, windows, python-imaging-library, centering

When I try:

```
import Image
import ImageDraw
import ImageFont

def draw_text_center(im, draw, text, font, **kwargs):
    text_size = draw.textsize(text, font)
    return draw.text(
        ((im.size[0] - text_size[0]) / 2, (im.size[1] - text_size[1]) / 2),
        text, font=font, **kwargs)

im = Image.new('L', (64, 64), 0xFF)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
draw_text_center(
    im, draw, "Hello",
    ImageFont.truetype(os.path.expandvars("%SystemRoot%/Fonts/segoeui.ttf"), 16))
del draw
im.show()
```

I frustratingly get back non-vertically-centered text:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? How do I center the text correctly?

Comment: I'm on Mac OS, and I don't have segoeui, but when I use the system default font (by passing "None" in for the font argument), your code correctly centers the text.  Have you tried other fonts?

Comment: @Brionius: Yes, it suffers the same problem with Tahoma, Courier, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, since I can't reproduce this problem on Mac OS, but it *looks* like your system is anchoring the text by the *lower* left corner instead of the *upper* left corner, as it should be according to the documentation.

It could be a coincidence, but see if this works consistently:

```
return draw.text(
    ((im.size[0] - text_size[0]) / 2, (im.size[1] + text_size[1]) / 2),
    text, font=font, **kwargs)
#                                                ^^^
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But nope, that doesn't seem to be the case either unfortunately. The best result I can get is with `(im.size[1] - text_size[1] / 2) / 2`, but while that's centered for Segoe UI, it's not consistent between fonts -- it's still un-centered for some fonts so I'm not sure what it's doing...